# How to write a method that takes an array of strings and prints each of them?

Tags: java, arrays

I need to gain a better understanding of methods and arrays.

This is what I've done but I don't think its right

```
String a = 1;
String b = 2;
String [] arr = String [a + b];
System.out.println(arr);
```

Comment: Have a look at [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) and [Control Flow Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html) from Oracle's Java Tutorials.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at any of the thousands of Java tutorials available on the internet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simplest way to print an array in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java)

Comment: Google is our guru , certainly know a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You need to come up with something.. We can only help if you try, if you help yourself. But here's something you can start with...

```
public void print(String[] args)
{
    for(String s:args)
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

Update: I dint get exactly what are you trying to do by ..

`String[] arr= String[a+b];`

Anyway, if you want to create an array of Strings using Strings.. here's how you do it..

```
String a="Hello ";
String b="World!!";
String[] arr={a,b};
```

And for printing the strings, refer to the the answer above. If you will pass it to `println()`, it will call `toString()` which will print it in a particular format.

Answer (score 1):

Its always better to explore and learn before posting here.
anyway use below code:

```
public void printString(String[] strings){
    for(String string:strings)
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

Your code should be changed to:

```
String a = "1";
String b = "2";
String[] arr = {a,b};
```

Comment: this code didnt do anything for me

Comment: It is working fine. There is some problem in your string initialisation. I am updating the code.

Answer (score 0):

First you should understand what are arrays and methods and how they work.

Array:

Array is a systematic collection of objects or elements.
You define an array to store elements of particular type.
For Example:

```
String str[10];
```

would define an array of 10 string objects.

You also need to allocate [memory for objects before using them](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html).

Also have a look at [Steps in the memory allocation process for Java objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320980/java-memory-allocation-for-objects) for better understanding.

Methods:

A method is a subroutine associated with a class.

For a good basic understanding of methods look at [Defining methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

As far as your specific question is considered, you should read the [control structures](http://www.studiesinn.com/learn/Programming-Languages/Java-Language/Control-Structure.html).

You are doing

```
String[a+b]
```

which doesn't seem to be doing at all what you intend.

While reading the control structures, do take a good look at for and while looping structures.